# Winapi MIDI C++ program - undefined reference to midiOutGetNumDevs@0

Tags: c++, winapi, linker, midi

I am working on my bachelor thesis, and I encounter problems when using Windows MIDI. I am using C++ and the Codeblocks IDE.

Here is the code from the class header

```
#ifndef MIDISENDER_H
#define MIDISENDER_H


#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MidiSender
{
    private:
        HMIDIOUT devHandle;
        MIDIOUTCAPS devInfo;
        unsigned int totalDevs;
        vector <string> devList;

    public:
        MidiSender();

        void openDevice();
        void openDevice(unsigned int dev);
        void closeDevice();

    private:
        void getAllDevices();
        void setDevice(unsigned int dev);
};

#endif // MIDISENDER_H
```

And here is the constructor, where the problem occurs:

```
#include "midisender.h"

MidiSender::MidiSender()
{
    totalDevs=midiOutGetNumDevs();
    cout << "Total devices MIDI out: " << totalDevs << endl;
}
```

Also, I have added a linker directive `-mwindows`, but it has no effect. I think it must be be a problem somewhere during the linking phase. Could you please give me advice on how to get this to work?

Comment: which compiler are you using? if it's not visual c++ it may be that the #pragma comment statement is not supported and you have to link against winmm.lib on the command line.

Comment: I am using G++ MinGW compiler. So i should try Visual C++ compiler?

Comment: No, you just have to specify -lwinmm (or -lwinmm.lib?) as a linker option. Your code uses #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib") which isn't supported by mingw. That's why the linker doesn't find the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works now.. it was -lwinmm linker flag